# facebook ad api access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use the facebook graph api for creating custom audience.
The doc says
For an app to do ad management, a user (including an app developer) must give the app permission. This permission is called the ads_management extended permission.

Any idea how can i get the ads_management permission. Can that be applied to an account or will that need an app creation?
Please share any doc links.
Thanks
Pradeep S

Comment: When you ask the user for login, at that point you need to add what permission do you will need from him.  Read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Answer (score 1):

The ads_management permission is available as part of the Facebook Ads API, an API on top of the Graph API that's of restricted use. To use the Ads API and thus the ads_management permission you'll need to have your app approved by Facebook as per the [Ads API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview). The form for requesting Ads API access is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access